Unexpected Extra Customer Creation When Polling with Stripe API in Go
I'm working on a Go application that involves polling Stripe for customer and subscription information based on a user's login. The goal is to check if a customer or their subscription exists and is active. However, I've encountered an issue where it seems an extra customer is being created whenever these polling functions are called, which is not the intended behavior.
I've implemented two functions, pollForCustomerByLogin and pollForCustomerSubscriptionsByLogin, which use the Stripe API to search for customers and their subscriptions, respectively. These functions are supposed to only search and log the results without creating or modifying any data. Here's a simplified version of what the polling functions look like:
// This function polls for a customer by login until found or max attempts reached.
func pollForCustomerByLogin(t *testing.T, login string, maxAttempts int, sleepDuration time.Duration) {
    for attempt := 0; attempt < maxAttempts; attempt++ {
        // Define search parameters
        searchParams := &stripe.CustomerSearchParams{
            SearchParams: stripe.SearchParams{
                Query:  fmt.Sprintf("Metadata[\"login\"]:\"%s\"", login),
                Single: true,
            },
        }
        // Perform search
        result := customer.Search(searchParams)
        if result.Next() {
            fmt.Println("Customer found:", result.Customer().ID)
            return
        }
        fmt.Printf("Customer with login %s not found. Attempt %d of %d\n", login, attempt+1, maxAttempts)
        time.Sleep(sleepDuration)
    }
    t.Errorf("Customer with login %s not found after %d attempts", login, maxAttempts)
}

// This function polls for active subscriptions of a customer by login until found or max attempts reached.
func pollForCustomerSubscriptionsByLogin(t *testing.T, login string, maxAttempts int, sleepDuration time.Duration) {
    for attempt := 0; attempt < maxAttempts; attempt++ {
        // Define search parameters
        searchParams := &stripe.SubscriptionSearchParams{
            SearchParams: stripe.SearchParams{
                Query:  fmt.Sprintf("status:\"active\" AND metadata[\"login\"]:\"%s\"", login),
                Single: true,
            },
        }
        // Perform search
        result := subscription.Search(searchParams)
        if result.Next() {
            fmt.Println("Subscription for Customer found:", result.Subscription().ID)
            return
        }
        fmt.Printf("Subscription for Customer with login %s not found. Attempt %d of %d\n", login, attempt+1, maxAttempts)
        time.Sleep(sleepDuration)
    }
    t.Errorf("Subscription for Customer with login %s not found after %d attempts", login, maxAttempts)
}

I expected these functions to only search for and log existing customers or subscriptions without creating or modifying any Stripe data. However, after running these polling functions, I noticed an extra customer was created in Stripe, which is puzzling since there's no explicit creation logic in the functions.

The code you shared is not creating new Customers.
To figure out what created the new Customer you see, I recommend:

Open the Customer in the Stripe Dashboard
Scroll to the bottom of the page to see the Logs section
Click on the last request on the list, maybe something like POST /v1/customers
This will show you the exact API request that created that Customer.

